# how to extract a string between two patterns using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a below line in a pom.xml file.

```
<abc>xyz</abc>
```

I need to extract xyz by doing a pattern matching using batch script same like sed -e 's/(.*)/\1/'

and the output should be xyz.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Would Powershell be an option?

Comment: most of the bit is been done in batch. Only a small part is left. So powershell wont be an option in my case.

Comment: Why? a [tag:powershell] command can be run from a [tag:batch-file]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<>` as delims.

```
@for /f "tokens=2delims=><  " %%i in ('type pom.xml') dodo set "result=%%i" & goto :show
:show
echo %result%
```

or if you want a specific value only based on the property name of the tag..

```
@for /f "tokens=2delims=><  " %%i in ('type pom.xml ^| find /I "abc"') do set "result=%%i" & goto :show
:show
echo %result%
```

Comment: I get the "abc" printed here not xyz. I want xyz as output

Comment: input should be the pattern which is <abc></abc> and whatever is between the pattern that should be the output. i.e., xyz.

Comment: No again the output is "abc". I guess the code is still the same.

Comment: The string has a tab. It will always be checkedout from SVN so the tab will be there always.

Comment: Yes working now.. There are multiple occurances now and I want only the first occurance. Can you please help with that as well?

Comment: I meant, The pom.xml has multiple <abc> tags and I need the first occurance. But still I get all the occurances.

Comment: Can we cleanup the comments here please.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat):

```
call xpath.bat pom.xml "//abc"
```

to save it to a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat pom.xml "//abc"') set "abc_value=%%#"
echo %abc_value%
```

Comment: @Sumith08 - to see how this will work you can download xpath.bat in the same directory as your script and test it...